Estoy creando un juego con Ursina, pero tengo un problema con ciertas combinaciones de teclas
En este codigo se supone que el juego solo se sale al presionar Esc, sin embargo al presionar Shift+Q tambien se sale, esto es inconveniente porque estas dos teclas ya tienen otra funcion y a veces deben ser presionadas juntas (sin que se cierre el juego)
def update():
    global last_space_press_time, double_space_press_interval
    print(player.position)
    coords_text.text = f'Coords: {player.position}'
    # Cerrar la ventana al presionar la tecla Esc
    if held_keys['escape']:
        application.quit()
        
    # Detectar doble toque en la tecla espacio para volar
    if held_keys['space']:
        if time.time() - last_space_press_time < double_space_press_interval:
            toggle_flight()  # Alternar entre volar y modo normal
        last_space_press_time = time.time()

    #volar hacia arriba o abajo con E y Q
    if is_flying:
        if held_keys['shift']:  #
            player.speed = fly_run_speed
        else:
            player.speed = fly_speed
        
        if held_keys['e']:  #Volar hacia arriba
            player.y += time.dt * fly_speed
        if held_keys['q']:  # Volar hacia abajo con Q
            player.y -= time.dt * fly_speed
    else:
        # Correr con Shift sin volar
        if held_keys['shift']:
            player.speed = run_speed
        else:
            player.speed = normal_speed 


Eso ocurre porque Shift+q es* el atajo de teclado para el botón de cierre de la ventana (ursina.window.exit_button). Para que el atajo quede sin efecto puedes simplemente deshabilitar el botón:
window.exit_button.enabled = False

o si quieres mantener el botón pero deshabilitar su atajo puede hacer:
window.exit_button.ignore_input = True


*Nota
El atajo de teclado ha sido cambiado en un commit de fecha de 22/05/2024. Los nuevos atajos son Ctrl+Shift+Alt+q y  Alt+F4.
Es de suponer que se verá reflejado en la siguiente versión que se lance en PyPi, por lo que el problema planteado no tendrá lugar en el futuro, igual que si se instala Ursina actualmente usando la rama main del repo directamente.
